# How to strip stdout before logging into file?

Tags: linux, bash, logging

Example :

```
./script >> log.txt
```

log.txt content :

```
1 - 2 - 3 _ 4/ 8
a - b , c - d/ 9
```

Before appending to file, I would like to extract the last number and then log it to the file.

log.txt new content should have :

```
8
9
```

Comment: Have a look at _man grep_

Comment: `./script | awk '{print $NF}' >> log.txt`.

Comment: @fashuai : _extract the last number_ : So if the input line is `AB C 25 DX` it means that the logfile should contain `25`, right?

Comment: Thank you @oguzismail, I was looking for the syntax